vector fonts OCR Traineddata
what are the best OCR models for recognizing vector fonts, specifically styles like ISOCP.shx? I’ve trained a Tesseract OCR model, but it isn’t very effective with this type of font.
The text is in an image, but the image is embedded within a PDF file. The software is implemented in Python. I’ve trained a Tesseract OCR model, but it isn’t very effective with this type of font.
